# Refresh DIV content when sidebar is minimized

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi my problem is that am looking for a snippet or method in JavaScript/jquery to refresh the way contents fit in the main div when the sidebar is minimized. Am trying to get the contents to automatically re-size and fit in their own divs properly according to the new width but i can't seem to get it right. Am currently using Bootstrap.
 Here is an image showing before the sidebar is minimized:

[image: Before]

and After the sidebar is minimized

[image: After]

I apologize if you can not understand what i have written, i am trying my best to explain it as this is my first question here.

I have tried using *.load* function and other jquery functions.

Comment: I see no difference between both pictures. Also, you need to share what you've tried so far or provide a link where we can see this sidebar in action.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using this component: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart, as it is canvas, it will not resize on its own. You may need to redraw.